# TypeError: class() takes no arguments in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I am using pycharm for python and pygame module to create a game, I was following instruction from a book and I faced this problem:

I have a ship class

[snapshot of ship class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5apWs.png)

and I have the main class which is:

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
    ship = Ship(screen)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    ship.blitme()
    # setting the color of screen to yellow
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_game()
```

but I keep getting the error
**ship = Ship(screen)**
**TypeError: Ship() takes no arguments**

and I alread have

```
def __init__(self, screen)
```

in ship class
[snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czCJc.png)

Comment: Your code clearly reads `def __int__`

Comment: If your code is the same as in the example above, then take a look at the indentation, the `__init__` method should be intended one level inside the class.

Comment: Above code, `__int__` is a typo. Did you replicate the same mistake in your program?

Comment: Pasting the code and errors directly in the question is better than posting that as a screenshot. Makes it more accessible. Please revert to the text only version if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, you've written `__int__` instead of `__init__`. Fix that and it should make the error go away.

Comment: Do not answer typo questions!

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh really? Didn't know there's any rule regarding that. Is there any written stackoverflow rule regarding this or is it just an informal convention? If there is, can you link me to it?

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.

Comment: See also [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo), [Closing questions with typos faster: typo-hammer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer/319503#319503) and [Should we answer or comment on a typo question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Got it, thank you!